# How do I find the order of an element if I am given the minimal polynomial of the element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

For example, let's say I am given an element $α$ in a field of characteristic $2$. Further, I am given the minimal polynomial of α with respect to $GF(2)$. Let's say that minimal polynomial is $f(x) = x^9 + x + 1$. How would I then deduce the order of $α$?

This is for a coding theory assignment, but I cannot deduce from the literature how to go in this direction. Most things I have read seem to indicate how to find a minimal polynomial, but don't seem to take that any further.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\alpha^9 = \alpha + 1$. Squaring, you get $(\alpha^9)^2 = (\alpha+1)^2 = \alpha^2+1$, and squaring again twice yields $(\alpha^9)^8 = \alpha^8+1$. Multiplying by $\alpha$, you get $\alpha^{8 \cdot 9+1} = \alpha^9 + \alpha = 1$, hence the order of alpha divides $8 \cdot 9 + 1 = 73$, which is prime.

**EDIT:** I just thought of a way to expand on this. Since $[\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_2] = 9$, we have $\mathbb{F}_2(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_{2^9}$ meaning that the order of $\alpha$ divides $|(\mathbb{F}_{2^9})^\times| = 511 = 7 \cdot 73$ by Lagrange's theorem. If the order were $7$, then we would have $\alpha^7-1=0$ and thus $X^7-1$ would divide the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, which is clearly not the case. Thus, the only possibilities are $73$ and $511$, and since we saw that $\alpha^{73}=1$, we get the answer.

It would be interesting to know if we can get this result without the computation from the beginning though.

Comment: So would that mean my order for α is 73?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, yes.

Comment: I am with you through most of that answer (essentially you are deriving a conjugacy class for α^9, correct)?
I am not understanding this portion though:
Multiplying by α, you get α^(8*9+1) = α^9 + α = 1, hence the order of α divides 8*9+1 = 73

Comment: What is it you don't understand?

Comment: Is there some theorem that states the order of the element divides the exponent of the first time it cycles around?
i.e. what is the justification that the order of alpha divides 8*9+1? I just don't remember having seen a theorem in my course that stated/proved that fact

Comment: I don't know if it is a theorem really, it follows from the definition of the order. The order is the smallest exponent $k$ for which $\alpha^k = 1$, thus every power $l$ such that $\alpha^l = 1$ is a multiple of the order $k$, since $\alpha^{(k+1)}$, $\alpha^{(k+2)}$, ... will not be 1 again until $\alpha^{(k+k)}$ is reached, since $\alpha^{(k+n)} = a^n \neq 1$ when $0 < n < k$.

Comment: @hrt Could I ask you something about coding theory?

Comment: @Evinda Why me specifically?

Comment: @hrt I thought that it would be one of your fields. Isn't it?

Comment: @Evinda Not really. If you have something to ask, it is probably better to create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

As a minor variation on hrt's answer:

We know that $\alpha^9 = \alpha + 1$. Since $(a+b)^{2^m} = a^{2^m} + b^{2^m}$ in a field of characteristic $2$, we have that 
\begin{align}
(\alpha^9)^8 &= (\alpha + 1)^8\\
&= \alpha^8 + 1\\
&\Downarrow\\
\alpha^{72} &= \alpha^8+1\\
&\Downarrow\\
\alpha^{73} & = \alpha^9+\alpha\\
&= 1.
\end{align}
Thus, $\mathsf{ord}(\alpha)$ is $73$ or a factor thereof,
and since $73$ is a prime and $\alpha \neq 1$, it must be that $\mathsf{ord}(\alpha)=73$.

The answer is not so easy to get at in general: this
particular case leads to a simple calculation. Try
finding the order of the roots of $x^4+x^3+1 \in \mathbb F_2[x]$ using the above "trick" to see what I mean.The
*period* of a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb F[x]$ is
defined to be the smallest integer $n$ such that $f(x)$
is a divisor of $x^n-1$, and if $f(x)$ is an irreducible
polynomial of degree $m$, then $n$ is a divisor of
$|\mathbb F|^m-1$.